# SQL Server why Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
from 
    (select * 
     from 
         (select t1.stdid
         from t1) as table1
     cross join 
         select * 
         from 
             (select t2.Subid
              from t2) as table2
    ) as table3
```

Comment: what is your expected output here?

Comment: You are selecting 1 column so I am not sure what all those `select *` are all about and even if you need them.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a step back and rethink your query. I can almost promise there is a better way to accomplish your end result.

Comment: @LKTN.25 i expect this query will make cross join between two columns

Comment: Simply `select t1.stdid, t2.Subid from t1 cross join t2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the query below. You included an addition select * from that you should have left out.

```
select *
from (
 select * 
 from (
    select t1.stdid
    from t1
    ) as table1
cross join 
-- select * from : This line is extraneous and is causing your error.
   (
    select t2.Subid
    from t2
    ) as table2
) as table3
```

Alternatively, you will get the same result if your query was written as:

```
 select * 
 from (
    select t1.stdid
    from t1
    ) as table1
cross join 
   (
    select t2.Subid
    from t2
    ) as table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use * in the query. Just select the column which you want.Please see below:

```
select ID
from 
    (select t1.id as ID
     from 
         (select t1.id
         from t1) as t1
     cross join 

             (select t2.id
              from t2) as t2
    ) as table3
```